# Bash, checking command return and then echo it

Tags: bash

In the following piece of code, even if pdfinfo exits with `1`, in the echo the `$?` prints `0`. So, what is it outputting, the exit value from the `if`?

```
if ! pdfinfo "${NOMBRE_PDF}" 2>> /dev/null > /dev/null
      then
        echo "El pdf generado no es válido codigo del pdfinfo = $?" >> "${ARCHIVO_LOG}"
```

Comment: With Bash, `pdfinfo "${NOMBRE_PDF}" 2>> /dev/null > /dev/null` can simply be `pdfinfo "${NOMBRE_PDF}" &>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `!` inverts the exit status, so the zero value is correct. For example:

```
$ false; echo $?
1
$ ! false; echo $?
0
```

You will have to find another way to capture the exit status:

```
pdfinfo … || echo …
```

would be one way.

Other ways:

```
# Hat tip: konsolebox
if pdfinfo "${NOMBRE_PDF}" 2>> /dev/null > /dev/null; then
  :
else
  echo "El pdf generado no es válido codigo del pdfinfo = $?" >> "${ARCHIVO_LOG}"; ...
fi

until pdfinfo "${NOMBRE_PDF}" 2>> /dev/null > /dev/null; do
  echo "El pdf generado no es válido codigo del pdfinfo = $?" >> "${ARCHIVO_LOG}"; ...
  break
done
```

Comment: `if pdfinfo "${NOMBRE_PDF}" 2>> /dev/null > /dev/null; then :; else echo "El pdf generado no es válido codigo del pdfinfo = $?" >> "${ARCHIVO_LOG}"; ...; fi`

Comment: @konsolebox Thanks, I added that to the answer.

Comment: No prob. You're welcome. Your answer and this question is quite unique. Rarely does one notices that ! inverts $? permanently.